# LIMIT number of rows

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table showing how often a customer access the site.
I want to limit the number of rows to 4500 only without using the limit clause or allowing a user to select this field and enter a number of rows they want to limit on
e.g column row_limit = 300. this will limit the table down to 300 rows. Each customer id is unique and no duplicate.

| customer_id | row_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 |  |

Comment: "*without using the limit clause*" - why?

Comment: As this table will be used to allow users to limit rows dynamically. it would be easier if i can limit 8 million of records by using the LIMIT clause that would be ok but then that table cannot be used over and over again because it will just be 4500 records all the time.

Comment: @Don_g_ta So you want to somehow do a `JOIN perUserRowLimits AS lim ... LIMIT lim.row_count`  ?

Comment: @Dai are you able to tell me more please?

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` clause is used on `SELECT` queries. Output will stop after the given number of rows. It is typically used with an `ORDER BY` clause to determine which rows will be shown.

The clause does *not* change the number of rows in the underlying table.

Comment: It might as I will be creating the table and limiting the number of rows to 4500 as an example. Then I will upload that to an S3 bucket. I am not sure if that will change the rows that someone will see or they will be able to see a full 8 million of rows.

Comment: @Don_g_ta That makes even less sense - why are you uploading a PostgreSQL/Redshift database table to S3?

Comment: It's hard to explain. I create a table that captures how often a customer visit our site for the last 6 months. Once that done, I need to see who are our top 4500 customers are. I then create a feature selection for other employee to use so in the near future, if they want to select a larger portion of customer they can. LIMIT clause  might not work.

Comment: @Don_g_ta I think you're overcomplicating things...